# why have the same V before and after resistor?

Tags: voltage, resistors, measurement, breadboard

I'm starting in electronics, and some measurements are surprising to me...
Why i have the same V before and after a resistor? I've taken two photos to illustrate it, any advice will be very appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

[image: measurement 1]

[image: measurement 2]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLNgbb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: There's only a voltage drop across a resistor if there's a current flowing through it. Have you completed the circuit to allow current to flow?

Comment: You need to show a schematic of each measurement, it's not possible to guess what you're measuring from the photos, nice though they are, edit your post and use the schematic button.

Comment: note: both measurements use the red tester in same wire (left). Black tester moves from left to right wire on resistance.

Comment: The circuit is similar to it, difference is I don't have a led. I have two simple wires, but in essence the question is: Why I get the same V value before and after resistor? I't browen, or not working?

Comment: So the circuit you've drawn isn't the right circuit. It sounds like only one end of the resistor is connected, so there isn't a circuit through it and therefore both ends have the same potential.

Comment: "The circuit is similar to it" doesn't quite cut it when it comes to electronics. You're getting the wrong result when measuring and the circuit is correct so there's obviously an important difference between the circuit and reality. To help you we need to know _exactly_ how everything is connected.

Comment: Yes, circuit is wrong I see it. Indeed, there is no circuit because current is not moving... The two wires (measured by red point) are not connected :S. Sorry for the mistake, and thanks for the indications!

Answer (score 4):

The resistor is only connected to the negative rail.  The other side of resistor, which is on the central board area (I have no idea what that area is called) is not connected to anything.

On a bread board, the power rails (the strips of 2 that run vertically) are connected.  On the central plains, the strips are connected horizontally.  There does not appear to be a connection between the red jumper and the resistor.

Here's a bit more information on exactly what makes up a bread board:
https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-breadboard

Comment: Oh I see, what a dumb mistake...So circuit is not closed! I'll try when I arrive home, thanks for the explanation!